# How can I display my stats account at my personal webpage?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I would like to place my stats-stackexchange account on my personal website, like is done on the about page here:
[image]

But I can't figure out how.

Comment: Looks great!  http://www.psychologie.uni-freiburg.de/Members/singmann

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under your [name](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/users/442/henrik), there is a "Got flair?" link. Click on that.